# Find matrix such that:

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Find matrix such that:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 3 \\ 
 3 & 6 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix} X+ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=2X $$
 inverse of which matrix i have to find? How to approach that?

Comment: $2X=2EX$, where $E$ is identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that
$$ AX +B  = 2X \implies  (A-2I)X = -B \implies   X = - (A-2I)^{-1}B.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you should write it like that:

$\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 3 \\ 
 3 & 6 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix} X+ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}X$

or

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
 3 & 4 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix} X=\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
 -1 & 1 & -2 \\ 
 -1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$